# Canny detection in python with openCV

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I applied a canny edges detection on an image and I get as a result this image:

[image]

I get the coordinates of this, using:

```
ans = []
for y in range(0, edges.shape[0]):
    for x in range(0, edges.shape[1]):
        if edge[y, x] != 0:
            ans = ans + [[x, y]]
ans = np.array(ans)
```

But I would like only the contour of this shape not what is inside. Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You should try using hierarcy in the contour to define which is parent and which is child, and then you can loope inside the hierarcy and draw only the parent contours (or the outermost contours).

For example take a look at this image

[image]

contours 0, 1, 2 are the outermost contours or we can also says hierarchy-0, and then comes contours 2a which is hierarchy-1 and then contours 3 which is hierarchy-2 and so on.

From here you can determine how deep you should keep your hierarchy.

For further reference you can check OpenCV Documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html#gsc.tab=0)